# How to perform feature selection (rfecv) in cross validation in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I want to perform `recursive feature elimination with cross validation (rfecv)` in 10-fold cross validation (i.e. `cross_val_predict` or `cross_validate`) in sklearn.

Since `rfecv` itself has a cross validation part in its name, I am not clear how to do it. My current code is as follows.

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")

k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

rfecv = RFECV(estimator=clf, step=1, cv=k_fold)
```

Please let me know how I can use the data `X` and `y` with `rfecv` in `10-fold cross validation`.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Would you like to use RFE in conjunction with the classifier in each fold, or what?

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you for the comment. I would like to do `10-fold cross validation` with feature selection in sklearn. is it possible to do? :)

Comment: You have already said that, and this is exactly what the existing answer provides, but you still seem not satisfied. I have asked something different - why BTW the random forest code in the question, if it is irrelevant? You want to do CV with the RF classifier trained in the RFE-selected features?

Comment: @desertnaut I got your point now. Thank you for the clarification. Yes, I want to do CV with RF classifier trained in RFE selected features. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use recursive feature elimination in conjunction with a pre-defined `k_fold`, you should use [`RFE`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) and not `RFECV`:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")
selector = RFE(clf, 5, step=1)

cv_acc = []

for train_index, val_index in k_fold.split(X, y):
    selector.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    pred = selector.predict(X[val_index])
    acc = accuracy_score(y[val_index], pred)
    cv_acc.append(acc)

cv_acc
# result:
[1.0,
 0.9333333333333333,
 0.9333333333333333,
 1.0,
 0.9333333333333333,
 0.9333333333333333,
 0.8666666666666667,
 1.0,
 0.8666666666666667,
 0.9333333333333333]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is exactly what I was looking for. thank you for correcting me in `rfe`. :)

Comment: Useful to me as well, might like to have mean of cv_acc though.

Answer (score 0):

To perform feature selection with `RFE` and *then* fit a `rf` with 10 fold cross validation, here's how you could do it:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")
rfe = RFE(estimator=rf, step=1)
```

Now transform the original `X` by fitting with the `RFECV`:

```
X_new = rfe.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Here are the ranked features (not much of a problem with only 4 of them):

```
rfe.ranking_
# array([2, 3, 1, 1])
```

Now split into train and test data and perform a cross validation in conjunction with a grid search using `GridSearchCV` (they usually go together):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_new,y,train_size=0.7)

k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

param_grid = {
                 'n_estimators': [5, 10, 15, 20],
                 'max_depth': [2, 5, 7, 9]
             }

grid_clf = GridSearchCV(rf, param_grid, cv=k_fold.split(X_train, y_train))
grid_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = grid_clf.predict(X_test)

confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

array([[17,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11,  0],
       [ 0,  3, 14]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. However, I would like to use 10-fold cross validation, instead of train and test split. i.e. something like `cross_val_predict`. Is it possible to do with rfecv? Thank you :)

Comment: You're doing 10 fold cross validation. The only detail is that you're leaving an unseen test sample to get realistic metrics @emj

Comment: This is not advisable methodologically; selecting features using all the data (even through a separate CV procedure) and then use this selected features with CV is a known road to ruin. Correct approach is to wrap both in one single CV process, as shown in own answer. See [How NOT to perform feature selection!](https://www.nodalpoint.com/not-perform-feature-selection/) and the numerous links & references therein.

Comment: Hmm you raise a good point @desertnaut. DIdn't think of it in that way. So following this same approach with a `RFE` (hence no cross-val) should be okay, right?

Comment: @yatu yeah, more or less. It's a fine point that has literally destroyed people in the past :)

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know (never really ended up with such an approach). Also not convinced though with using RFE to perform feature selection using all the data. Isn't that a little "dangerous" too?@desertnaut

Comment: I think my natural tendency would be to train using train data, and then transform both `X_train` and `X_test` accordingly @desertnaut